# Hopf Algebras Arising From Fourier Transforms?

Tags: fourier-analysis, hopf-algebras

At least for nice functions, a Fourier series is just a Laurent series on a circle (which means just substituting $z = re^{i\theta}$ into a Laurent series), so I can see Fourier analysis on Abelian groups as generalizing this simple example.

How do I see (in an easy way) that Hopf Algebras are the natural generalization of Fourier theory to algebras, in a way that motivates what a Hopf algebra is:

> [A third point of view](http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/what-is.pdf) is that Hopf algebras are the next simplest
>   category after Abelian groups admitting Fourier transform.